# Blazor build hangs in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, blazor

I'm putting this out here to save someone else some of my pain.  Today I built my Blazor solution and it simply hung. Searching on this will give you alot of results that have nothing to do with Blazor.

There was no indication as to what happened and I didn't find out until I tried updating VS that a Node.exe process running on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Node.exe is the NodeJS process that is used by VS as a debugger proxy for the client-side WASM project.  Kill the Node.exe process and you should be able to build again.